# AWS lambda python Socket exception: Operation not permitted (1)

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, paramiko

I have a python 3.6 AWS lambda function "ftp_sender" which is triggered by ObjectCreated event from S3. Then it downloads the file and sends it to the SFTP server.

And in CloudWatch logs I'm constantly seeing the messages like that:

`[ERROR]    2018-07-26T12:30:21.543Z    a56f9678-90c9-11e8-bf10-ddb8557d0ff0    Socket exception: Operation not permitted (1)`

This messages appear in random positions even before the function started working, for example:

```
def ftp_sender(event, context):
    # The error can be triggered here
    print(event)
```

This seems not treated as a real error, but maybe someone knows what it is about?

[EDIT]
It looks like the issue caused by paramiko library. I have the following class inside the function:

```
    class SftpSender:

    def __init__(self, hostname, username, the_password, sftp_port=22, working_directory=''):
        self.hostname = hostname
        self.username = username
        print('SFTP port: %s' % sftp_port)
        self.transport = paramiko.Transport((hostname, sftp_port))
        self.transport.connect(username=username, password=the_password)
        self.sftp = paramiko.SFTPClient.from_transport(self.transport)
        # self.transport.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.WarningPolicy())
        self.folder = working_directory

    def send_file(self, filename, retries=4, timeout_between_retries=10, verb=True, the_lambda_mode=False):
        retry_number = 0
        sending_result = 'Not run'
        if the_lambda_mode:
            os.chdir("/tmp/")

        if not os.path.isfile(filename):
            return "Error: File %s is not found" % filename

        while retry_number < retries:
            if verb:
                print('Sending %s to %s@%s (to folder "%s") retry %s of %s\n' % (filename, self.username, self.hostname, self.folder, retry_number, retries))

            try:
                destination_name = self.folder + '/' + filename
                sending_result = self.sftp.put(filename, destination_name)
                return 'OK'
            except Exception as e:
                print('Error: The following exception occured: "%s", result: "%s"' % (e, sending_result))
                sleep(timeout_between_retries)
                retry_number += 1
                return 'Error: failed to send file %s (%s)' % (filename, e)
```

Comment: This is a permissions problem with TCP sockets. Edit your post and include your code. Most likely you have buggy code or a broken library.

Comment: Did you ever resolve this or find a workaround?

Comment: Nope. I suspect it is something related to how I use paramiko, but since it is still working, it seems not a big deal

Comment: Are you ever closing the Paramiko connection? By default paramiko doesn't close it. I used connection.close() in a finally block to close this, and did not get errors afterwards.

Comment: Thanks @RakeshGuha. I added connection.close() call for all functions where I opened paramiko connections. It seems fixed the issue, I still see the error, but now only when I try to download files from S3:

 s3.Bucket('bucket_name').download_file(full_file_name, '/tmp/%s' % file_name)